# sony-camera-api trackingFocus

Tags: camera, sony

I can turn tracking Focus on and use the `actTrackingFocus`.  Once the `actTrackingFocus` is set how can I get the coordinates back from the camera so I can draw a box in the `Liveview` box showing what the camera is focused on?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with the existing API unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate that this is an old question, but if you are still trying and OK playing in python...

The tracking focus location is (apparently) reported via the frame info packets, and thus you have to enable them and then decode.

We are attempting to do this with pysony [1](https://github.com/mungewell/sony_camera_api)

Use 'python src/example/pygameLiveView -i' to see the reported locations. You might need to add your 'actTrackingFocus()' call to enable tracking focus, but they should be rendered (box with triangle corners) on screen.

Since none of the devs have a camera which support tracking focus, we'd love to hear whether it works on not. :-)